# Proper way of cancelling in Saga state machine

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a question related to cancellation of the Saga state machine instance that uses **RabbitMQ**. I have this scenario:

I have an API that exposes an endpoint which (when hit) publishes the initial message that kicks of chain of events in the state machine:

```
await _publishEndpoint.Publish<InitializeExport>(new { ExportId = request.ExportId, Payload = request.Payload });
```

where **ExportId** is the *CorrelationId* which is used for persistence (EntityFrameworkCore)

I read somewhere on github that the way to cancel Saga's chain of events is to publish ***CancelJob*** event. And with that said, I exposed another *"cancel"* endpoint which publishes this message:

```
await _publishEndpoint.Publish<CancelJob>(new { JobId = request.ExportId, Reason = request?.Payload?.Reason });
```

If I understood this right, when ***CancelJob*** is published, 'under the hood' it finds the ***context*** of the Job with the specified ***JobId*** (this needs to be same as the *CorrelationId* of the job that I want to cancel?) and it cancels the ***CancellationToken*** related with that ***context***

And in the consumer methods in order to check if the chain of events is canceled I need to have

`context.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationIsRequested()`

Which will throw an exception that I should propagate further and transition the Saga to the ***final*** state?

Well I've tried this above, and when ***CancelJob*** is published, the **CancellationToken** related with the **context** that I want to cancel stays the same, in other words

```
context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false
```

and the job isn't canceled.

Am I doing this right, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`CancelJob` is used to cancel a job consumer (if it hasn't already completed).

It has nothing to do with sagas.